# Difference between Lua and Python in hex conversion

Tags: python, lua, hex

In Python, I have:

```
>>> mac_string = "68:a8:6d:0b:90:46"
>>> mac_int = int((mac_string).replace(":", ""), 16)
>>> print(mac_int)
115072593268806
```

In Lua, I have:

```
> mac_string = "68:a8:6d:0b:90:46"
> mac_int = tonumber(mac_string:gsub(':',''),16)
> print(mac_int)
1.1507259326881e+14
```

Why is there a difference of 4?

Comment: On Lua 5.1 use `print(('%.f'):format(mac_int))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to Lua version 5.2, the Lua *number* type uses a floating point representation, whilst Python uses actual integers which are only bound by memory. From the [Lua 5.2 documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.1):

> Number represents real (double-precision floating-point) numbers.

Note that the number is still precise enough, but is *rounded for display*. If you convert the resulting integer to float in Python (which also uses a double-precision float) you can see that the same number is there:

```
>>> float(115072593268806)
115072593268806.0
>>> '{:.13e}'.format(float(115072593268806))
'1.1507259326881e+14'
```

The second line formats that number the same way Lua did; with 13 digits after the decimal point, using scientific notation.

You can tell Lua to use a different format to print the number using [`string.format`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.format):

```
print(string.format("%d", mac_int))
```

I see that Lua 5.3 [expanded the *number* type to support 64-bit integers](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1), so perhaps upgrading to that version solves this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Lua 5.1, by default, always stores numbers as 64-bit floating point values. `tostring` uses scientific notation for printing very large or small values.

If you use `string.format` to format the number, you can get all the digits:

```
> print(string.format("%15d", mac_int))
115072593268806
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Lua 5.2 or lower. The number type is by default `double` type in C. The default format of `print` doesn't have enough precision.

---

Lua 5.3 supports the integer subtype, which is by default 64-bit. The result of the same code outputs:

```
115072593268806
```